# Why Running multiple same commands take a very long time

Tags: linux, io, runtime

This isn't so much of a programming question, but more of a problem which I've encountered lately, which I'm trying to understand.

Example, running an `ls` command in `linux` take maybe ..... 1 sec.
But when I spawn off a few thousands of `ls` command simultaneously, I noticed that some of the process is not running, and kinda take a very long time to run.

Why is that so? And how can we work around that?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I did a `ps`, and saw that a couple of the `ls` commands were in the state of `D<`. I checked up a bit, and understand that it is an Uninterruptable Sleep. What is that? And when will that happen? How to avoid that?

Comment: Spawning a process is not free.

Answer (score 0):

The number of processes or threads that can be executing concurrently is limited by the number of cores in your machine.

If you spawn thousands of processes or threads simultaneously the kernel is only able to run 'n' (where n equals the number of available cores) at the same time, some of them will have to wait to be scheduled.

If you want to run more processes or threads truly concurrently then you need to increase the number of available cores in the system (ie. by adding CPUs, enabling hyperthreading if available).